# Resampling OHLC tick data and filling gaps in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, resampling

I have some tick data in this form:

```
date                 price    amount
2011-09-13 13:53:36  5.80     1.0000
2011-09-13 13:53:44  5.83     3.0000
2011-09-13 14:32:53  5.90     2.0000
```

And I've resampled the price with:

```
resampledData.price.resample('55min', how="ohlc")
```

Now I need to fill out the missing data and the only way I came up with was:

```
closes = resampledData.close
closes = closes.fillna(method='pad')
resampledData = resampledData.open.fillna(closes)
resampledData = resampledData.high.fillna(closes)
resampledData = resampledData.lowe.fillna(closes)
resampledData = resampledData.close.fillna(closes)
```

But this looks really bad, is there a more efficient way to do it?

Also, is there a way to ressample two columns at the same time? Like the price with "ohlc" and the amount with a method "sum"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For filling the NaNs, you can apply this on all columns in one line as follows:

```
closes = resampledData['close'].fillna(method='pad')
resampledData.apply(lambda x: x.fillna(closes))
```

You also have a `fillna` method for a DataFrame (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html), but this regards a Series as input as different values to use for different columns.

For the resampling, normally you can do the following to resample with different functions on multiple columns at once:

```
resampledData.resample('55min', how={'price':'ohlc', 'amount':'sum'})
```

But for me this does not seem to work with `ohlc` (if you change that to eg 'mean', then it does work).

Comment: Thank you. Indeed the 'ohlc' doesn't work right away, but if I build a dictionary with the method 1st (i.e. and ohlc_dict that does the same), then it works after that.

Comment: By the away, just one question. Using this method, I end up with two main columns (price, amount) and inside each of those columns I have (open, high low, close for the price and sum for the amount).
What is the way to access them? I'm using resampledData.amount.sum, but when I try resampledData['amount.sum'] it doesn't work.

Comment: You have then a MultiIndex (or hierarchical) column, and access it like: ``resampledData[('amount', 'sum')]`` See here http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#hierarchical-indexing-multiindex